# Ionic 3 horizontal scrolling cards

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

I'm trying to make horizontally scrolling cards like the ones in the image.
Does anyone know how to do this? I need the cards to have the same height regardless of the size of the image itself.

Thank you so much. You can try the cards I mean here:
https://www.appimin.com/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rJwO.png)

EDIT: this is what I've tried

slider.html

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" direction="x">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let dat of data">
      <img [src]="dat.attachments[0]" style="object-fit: cover;"/>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>
          {{ dat.title }}
        </p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-scroll>
```

slider.ts

```
.scroll-zoom-wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ion-card {
    width: 220px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100% !important;
}

ion-scroll {
    min-height: 200px; 
    height: auto;

        .scroll-content {
        padding: 0px !important;
    }    

}
```

[This is what I got. It scrolls fine, but all of them are different heights.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn6c4.png)

Comment: You should go ahead and post the code you have already tried, don't be shy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ion-slides for that:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-card> 
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

Than you can use simple css to get the proper height:

```
.card {
   height: 10vh;
}
```

For more information refer to:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/